# Why does Git report a random, non-existent directory or file as an untracked file?

Tags: git

After making a few changes within a repo, when I run a `git status` I get the following:

> Untracked files:
>    (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)
>
> ```
>    "etting\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\233\357\200\272"
> ```

This file does not exist. I'm not sure where the seemingly random numbers come from. Oddly, it's also surrounded in quotes. The status does also correctly show my modified files.

What could cause this? I've had it happen a few times before and had to perform a reset to return to a correct state. Is it possible the repo is corrupted in some way?

Comment: Those values look like octal to me - the bytes in the filename are probably (in hex) ef 80 9b ef 80 9b ef 80 9b ef 80 9b ef 80 ba. My guess is that's UTC-8, but I haven't checked.

Comment: I think you're right, but looking at the UTF-8 representation of those bytes it's still unrelated to any real file or directory.

Comment: Are you a Mac user?

Comment: @Sio: Agreed. Not sure why I said UTC-8 either - I definitely meant UTF-8, but when I tried it, those weren't valid Unicode characters. So yes, something odd is going on.

Comment: That's definitely weird. What OS and Git version?

Comment: Is something else accessing the repo? An IDE perhaps ? Does the file appear when you are actively using the repo or even after a period of inactivity? Am trying to figure out if git is the culprit or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you add an untracked file like ":q" it reports as "\357\200\272q" .

Answer (score 4):

You probably are committing a file you accidentally made called: "etting::::" or something similar. I had "c/357\200\272" because I accidentally made a file called 'c:' in that directory.

Just list what you have in that directory and you'll probably see the file that doesn't belong. Remove and you should be good.

Answer (score 2):

This might not be your exact same scenario, but I found that having the repo's local directory within my [odrive](https://www.odrive.com/) created this:

```sh
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        "\357\200\272"
```

I removed the repo from the odrive directory and then removed any files that had a file type of ".cloud" (which means the file is in the cloud and not on the local machine). I really don't know what exactly caused it, but this definitely fixed the problem for me.